# JQuery chat application scroll to bottom of div ONLY on new message?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, html

I have picked up this AJAX code from multiple tutorials, but the problem is, when the ajax is called, the div ALWAYS scrolls to the bottom. But I want it so that the div ONLY scrolls if there are new messages in the div.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "msg-handle/get-messages.php",
  cache: false,
  data: { room: $("#room").val() },
  success: function(data) { $('#chat').html(data)

$("#chat").scrollTop($("#chat")[0].scrollHeight);

  },
});

}, 500);
```

Is there a way to achieve this **without** any major ramifications to my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way would be to let the php script pass a flag when there are new messages in the div. you then just have to put in a check condition for the the scrolling.

another option would be to compare the number of divs in the new .get() result to the previous one and scroll only if there are more divs present in the current.

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting. I'll try that.

Comment: just thinking aloud… why not give the newest message a unique id? or attach a unique id with sequential numbers to every message? that way you don't run into problems when removing older messages (to avoid performance issues, by not having the browser to display the 8,000 messages of the conversation at once).

Comment: Well, I limit how many are shown in the log, but yeah, I was thinking that.

Comment: how to check how much divs in div?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't try it, but I think it has to be something like this... (among other solutions)

```
var oldscrollHeight = $("#chat")[0].scrollHeight;
                      //Takes the height BEFORE reload the div

$.ajax({
  url: "msg-handle/get-messages.php",
  cache: false,
  data: { room: $("#room").val() },
  success: function(data) { $('#chat').html(data)

    var newscrollHeight = $("#chat")[0].scrollHeight;
                          //Takes the height AFTER reload the div

    if(newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight){ //COMPARES
        $("#chat").scrollTop($("#chat")[0].scrollHeight); //Scrolls
    }
},
});
```

I think You have to put a `$("#chat").scrollTop($("#chat")[0].scrollHeight);` after the first load of the chat.. just an advise.