# Only scroll to bottom when a message a string is received for an Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Context**

I am trying to make my chat application so that it only scrolls to the bottom when a new message is received, I have tried using the solution mentioned in this question ([JQuery chat application scroll to bottom of div ONLY on new message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153975/jquery-chat-application-scroll-to-bottom-of-div-only-on-new-message)), however it did not work.  I have also seen two other questions however the code was much more complex than I feel is required.

**My Code**

```
var scroll = function() {
    function getMessages(letter) {
        var div = $("#chat");
        div.scrollTop(div.prop('scrollHeight'));
    }
    $(function() {
        getMessages();
    });
}

var newmessages = function() {
    setTimeout(newmessages, 5000);

    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "ajaxtesting.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html"
    });
    request.done(function(msg) {
        $("#chat").html(msg);
        scroll();
    });
    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
    });
}

newmessages();
```

As you can see the scroll function is currently called every time the Ajax is successful however, this simply scrolls to the bottom every 5 seconds. I tried using string length without much success, as I was getting weird string lengths that constantly changed even if there was no message being sent.

**Server side code**

```
     require_once('mysqli_connect.php');
     //$id = $_SESSION["user_id"]; 
     //$cid = $_SESSION["cid"];
     $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
     $cid = $_SESSION['cid'];
     $query = "SELECT text, sentuser, recieveuser, icebreaker 
     FROM convoreply  WHERE cid = $cid ORDER BY senttime ASC";
     $response = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
     if($response){
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)){ 
     $sentuser = $row['sentuser'];                       
     $text = $row['text']; 
     $recieveuser = $row['recieveuser'];  
     $icebreaker = $row['icebreaker'];      
     if ($sentuser == $id){    
     echo '<div class="bubble">',"<p>", $text,"<br/>\n","</p>",'</div>';  
     }
     if ($recieveuser == $id) {    
     echo '<div class="bubble2">',"<p>", $text,"<br/>\n","</p>",'</div>'; 
      }
      if ($icebreaker == 1) {    
     echo '<div class="bubble3">',"<p>", $text,"<br/>\n","</p>",'</div>'; 
     }
     if ($sentuser == 10000){
     echo '<div class="bubble3">',"<p>", $text,"<br/>\n","</p>",'</div>'; 
     }
     }}
     if ($cid == 0){
     echo '<p>Please click on a user on the left hand 
     side to view the conversation.</p>';
      }



      mysqli_close($dbc);
```

Comment: Could you show us how return response looks like?

Comment: I have added my server side code to the answer.

Comment: for this server-side code I would recommend check if there is a new message and if there is not -> return false - after that you can check it right in ajax response simply by if (msg) {....}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are binding to the `ajax.done` promise this will be executed regardless of whether there are any new messages.

```
request.done(function(msg) {
    if(msg !== null && msg !== "") {
        $("#chat").html(msg);   
        scroll();
    }
});
```

Something like the above is what you need.